# how to create video player in pyqt5 for windows to play mp4 using python code?

Tags: python, pyqt5, video-player

I tried to create video player for mp4 in windows 10 os. it is always showing error. i tried multiple method. but always failing

1. I tried code from this location https://pythonprogramminglanguage.com/pyqt5-video-widget/
   QMediaPlayer error:

[image]

2. I tried python-vlc. it is working only when I already installed vlc player. if i uninstalled vlc player it is not working

vlc error :

```
File "<module1>", line 7, in <module>
  File "D:\Portable_Python\App\Python\lib\site-packages\vlc.py", line 210, in <module>
    dll, plugin_path  = find_lib()
  File "D:\Portable_Python\App\Python\lib\site-packages\vlc.py", line 173, in find_lib
    dll = ctypes.CDLL(p)
  File "D:\Portable_Python\App\Python\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
>>>
```

3. tkvideoplayer

I tried code from this location https://github.com/PaulleDemon/tkVideoPlayer/blob/master/examples/sample_player.py

it is working fine. but I couldn't able it embed to pyqt5 window.

I attached example video file in this location
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AaTzf3LBUMCztO8hYpF9muPUImVDX1s_/view?usp=sharing

please give me a best solution in any one module.

I added simple code below . this is playing .avi file and not playing .mp4 files

```
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaContent, QMediaPlayer
import sys

class VideoPlayer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.video = QVideoWidget()
        self.video.resize(300, 300)
        self.video.move(0, 0)
        self.player = QMediaPlayer()
        self.player.setVideoOutput(self.video)
        self.player.setMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile("D:/2.mp4")))

    def callback(self):
        self.player.setPosition(0) # to start at the beginning of the video every time
        self.video.show()
        self.player.play()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    v = VideoPlayer()
    b = QPushButton('start')
    b.clicked.connect(v.callback)
    b.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: 1. I don't see any error, provide a [mre] and clarify what error you're talking about. 2. That's pretty obvious: it's called "python-vlc", isn't it? 3. Avoid mixing different toolkits, especially when dealing with audio/video.

Comment: tkvideoplayer is made for **Tkinter** and is made to provide a simple and quick way to play videos on tkinter. I don't think it could handle large files. You should go with `QMediaPlayer` and as musicmante suggested you should provide [mre].

Comment: Hi. we will go with 1st option QMediaPlayer . video is not playing, it is not printing any error. and status message (near play button) simply showing error without any description. I will create a simple code and demo video so that it will be clear. thankyou

Comment: @Viswa If you're on Windows, you will very likely need to [install some extra codecs](https://codecguide.com/download_kl.htm) to play MP4 files with QMediaPlayer.

Comment: yes. I think so. is it possible to play without installing codec with any other module. like opencv. because have to convert code as exe and use in another system. I don't know whether codecs installed in all system

Comment: @Viswa without a proper [mre] we cannot tell you what's wrong with your code. That said, no, there's no way to do that without codecs; there are dozens of audio and video formats (and media containers), not all of them can be distributed anywhere or are installed, and, most importantly, QMediaPlayer is *completely* dependent on the OS codecs: it doesn't work like cv which *physically* decodes the data, it does not *directly* play the content (unlike vlc), it is an interface with the multimedia API of the OS, so you can only use it as long as codecs are properly installed.

Comment: @Viswa if you want to distribute your program, you have to do it by also providing and installing those codecs, otherwise it will not work. There is no other (simple) alternative.

Comment: ok. thank you. then meanwhile I will I use cv module with ffpyplayer module to embed with pyqt5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As couldn't able to find direct player. I used cv module and ffpyplayer to integrate with pyqt5. it is temporarily resolved my issue. the code is given below.

```
from ffpyplayer.player import MediaPlayer

from PyQt5 import QtGui,QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys
import threading
import time
import cv2
from PIL import Image
import numpy
import os

class VideoPlayer:
    def __init__(self, filename,volume = 1.0):
        if not os.path.exists(filename):raise FileNotFound(filename)
        self.close = False
        self.state = None
        self.frame = None
        self.l=None
        self.filename = filename
        self.skip_interval=5

        self.player = MediaPlayer(filename, ff_opts={'sync': 'audio', 'paused': False, 'volume': volume, 't': 1e7+1, 'ss': 0})
        time.sleep(1)
        self.duration=self.player.get_metadata()['duration']
        handler_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.play, args=(), daemon=True)
        handler_thread.start()

    def play(self):
        while True:
            frame, self.val = self.player.get_frame()
            if self.val == 'eof':self.close=True
            if self.close == True:
                self.player.toggle_pause()
                self.player.close_player()
                time.sleep(2)
                break

            if isinstance(self.val, str) or self.val == 0.0:waitkey = 32
            else:waitkey = int(self.val * 100)
            pressed_key = cv2.waitKey(waitkey) & 0xFF

            if frame is None:continue

            image, pts = frame
            self.frame = (image, self.val)
            x, y = image.get_size()
            data = image.to_bytearray()[0]
            image =  Image.frombytes("RGB", (x, y), bytes(data))
            image = cv2.cvtColor(numpy.array(image), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
            self.frame=frame

            if self.l!=None:
                h, w, ch = image.shape
                Image2 = QImage(image.data, w, h, ch * w, QImage.Format_RGB888)
                self.pixmap=QPixmap.fromImage(Image2)
                self.l.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
                self.l.setFixedWidth(self.l.pixmap().width())
                self.l.setFixedHeight(self.l.pixmap().height())
                self.l.parent().update()
            del image


    def seek_p(self):
            if int(self.player.get_pts()) + self.skip_interval < int(self.duration):
                self.player.seek(self.skip_interval, relative=True, accurate=False)
    def seek_m(self):
        if int(self.player.get_pts()) - self.skip_interval > 0:
            self.player.seek(-self.skip_interval, relative=True, accurate=False)



class ed(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        vl=QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(vl)
        pb=QPushButton('play');vl.addWidget(pb);pb.clicked.connect(self.play)
        pb=QPushButton('stop');vl.addWidget(pb);pb.clicked.connect(self.close)
        pb=QPushButton('pause');vl.addWidget(pb);pb.clicked.connect(self.pause)
        pb=QPushButton('seek+');vl.addWidget(pb);pb.clicked.connect(self.seek_p)
        pb=QPushButton('seek-');vl.addWidget(pb);pb.clicked.connect(self.seek_m)
        pb=QPushButton('mute');vl.addWidget(pb);pb.clicked.connect(self.mute)
        pb=QPushButton('vol+');vl.addWidget(pb);pb.clicked.connect(self.vol_p)
        pb=QPushButton('vol-');vl.addWidget(pb);pb.clicked.connect(self.vol_m)
        self.l=QLabel();vl.addWidget(self.l)
    def play2(self):
        self.player=VideoPlayer('D:/2.mp4')
        self.player.l=self.l

    def play(self):
        self.t1=threading.Thread(target=self.play2)
        self.t1.start()

    def pause(self):self.player.player.toggle_pause()
    def seek_p(self):self.player.seek_p()
    def seek_m(self):self.player.seek_m()
    def mute(self):
        try:
            if (self.player.player.get_volume()>0.0):self.player.player.set_volume(0.0)
            else:self.player.player.set_volume(1.0)
        except:pass
    def vol_p(self):
        self.player.player.set_volume(self.player.player.get_volume() + 0.1)
        print(self.player.player.get_volume())
    def vol_m(self):
        self.player.player.set_volume(self.player.player.get_volume() - 0.1)
        print(self.player.player.get_volume())

    def close(self):
        try:
            self.player.close=True
            time.sleep(1)
        except:pass

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        try:
            self.player.close=True
            time.sleep(1)
        except:pass



if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window=ed()
    window.showMaximized()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```